# c++ LDLIBSOPTIONS makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to use some other project libraries in my implementation. The project has a /common folder where the libraries are located I want to include. In my makefile under LDLIBSOPTIONS, I included the path where /common folder is located like:

```
LDLIBSOPTIONS=-lpci -lpthread -I../../../OtherProj/Libs/common/
```

Then I include one .h file like:

```
#include <ExampleLib.h>
```

However I still get

```
fatal error: XXX.h: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?*  You are not specifying the directory containing the header file `XXX.h`.

Comment: As I said, the directory is /common and I am specifying it in the makefile  LDLIBSOPTIONS= -I../../../OtherProj/Libs/common/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LDLIBSOPTIONS` (more conventionally `LDFLAGS`) is used for specifying options to the linker.  You need to specify the directory, using the `-I` flag, in `CXXFLAGS`:

```
CXXFLAGS += -I../../../OtherProj/Libs/common/
```

However given you are using non-standard names for your Makefile variables, `CXXFLAGS` might be called something like `CXXOPTIONS`, but the exact name is unknown to me.

Once this is solved you're going to be getting linker errors until you start specifying the library path using `-L`; perhaps:

```
LDLIBSOPTIONS = -L../../../OtherProj/Libs/common/ -lpci -lpthread
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, after I added into CXXFLAGS, it worked and did not complain during linking as well. Should I also include it as you said: LDLIBSOPTIONS = -L../../../OtherProj/Libs/common/ in any case?